# C code question

Tags: c

When I entry a value for J variable,I am receive the error.

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main(void)
{

int num[0][0];
int ave, i, j;
int a ,b;
int sum = 0;

printf("Enter numbers of row for i");
scanf ("%d", a);
printf("Enter numbers of column for j");
scanf ("%d", b);

printf("Input matrix elements :");
for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
for (j = 0; j < b; j++) {

  printf("\nInput element [%d][%d] : ", i, j);
  scanf("%f", &num[i][j]);
}
}


printf("Your numbers are: \n");
for(i = 0; i < a; i++)
for(j = 0; j < b; j++)
printf("%4d",num[i][j]);




system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: What specific error do you receive?

Comment: My guess is that it's going to be a segfault.

Comment: I'm surprised that it even compiles. I'd put money on this being crusty old Turbo C.

Comment: @Paul: Turbo C Version 2.01 (with all the default options) gives an error for the `int num[0][0]` line: "Size of structure or array not known in function main" :D

Comment: @pmg: it seems I owe Borland an apology - these is evidently an even worse C compiler out there somewhere. ;-)

Comment: @Paul: Turbo C is a very decent pre-ANSI C compiler. I sometimes use it as another code validator. Depending on the chosen model I can, for example, make pointers to objects a different size than pointers to functions :)

Comment: @pmg: yes, back in the 1980s it was considered decent, especially as it only cost something like $50 IIRC.

Answer (score 3):

What error?

Anyway your problem is here:

```
printf("Enter numbers of row for i");
scanf ("%d", a);
printf("Enter numbers of column for j");
scanf ("%d", b);
```

It should be

```
scanf ("%d", &a);
scanf ("%d", &b);
```

Also your num matrix is 0 by 0. Try making it bigger or allocating it after reading a,b.

Comment: @Paul R: yes, but it probably is where the program ceases to work.

Answer (score 3):

```
scanf ("%d", &a);
scanf ("%d", &b);
```

And you need to malloc the 2D array if you want it to have variable size. Example:

```
int **num;
num = malloc(a * sizeof(int *));
int i;
for(i = 0; i < a; i++)
    num[i] = malloc(b * sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't allocate enough (or any) memory for `num[]`. You're going to need to allocate some memory for it, e.g.

```
int num[100][100];
```

Of course, you'll also have to make sure that i or j is not greater than 100 (in that case).

When using scanf, you need to pass pointers to the variables you want to scan in to, so it should be:

```
 scanf("%d", &a);
```

and so on.

Also, you don't `#include <stdlib.h>`, so I don't believe the `system()` function should be available to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
int num[0][0];
```

here's the problem. How many rows and how many columns do you want your matrix to have? Put it in the  brackets